# Ask user to print out the amount of number they want c#

Tags: c#, numbers, user-input, increment

I am having a bit issue with how I have to logically think for my code.
What I want to do is have the user type in how many numbers they want and then ask them where they want that sequence of numbers to start. Then I would print out the numbers. So if the user typed in 7 and then 4 the result would be 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.
Here is my code so far

```
int userInInt, userIntStart;
Console.Write("How many integers do you want to print? ");
userInInt = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("What is the first integer you want printed? ");
userIntStart = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

for(int counts = userIntStart; userIntStart <= userInInt; userIntStart++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(userIntStart);
}
```

I realized after doing this for loop that it would just be incrementing the starting number up until the userInInt which is not what I want. I've been spending a while trying figure out what else I need.
Thank you

Comment: I think you need to reevaluate that for loop. Don'y increment the userIntStart variable. Increment the counts variable

Comment: Along with what Brian said, I think the number you want to `WriteLine` is `counts` and you should be checking and incrementing `counts` after each iteration - `int counts = userIntStart; counts <= userInInt + userIntStart; counts++`; because right now `counts` is unused. Otherwise, you could just omit the first statement altogether.

Comment: But wouldn't the result for that be 4 5 6 7 if I change it like that? I want to try and get to be 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 for example if the user wants 7 number to printed starting from 4

Comment: No, because you increment until `counts <= userInInt + userIntStart`. Important: **+ userIntStart**.

Comment: OH, okay I think I understand why the +userIntStart was needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name you give to variables is important for the understanding of the code and makes it easier to think about it. `userInInt` does not reflect the purpose of the variable.

```
Console.Write("How many integers do you want to print? ");
int count = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("What is the first integer you want printed? ");
int start = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Often `i` is used as loop variable, because in math it is used as index. You have different choices as how you can formulate the loop. The most typical is

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(start + i);
}
```

But you can also add `start` to the loop variable start value and to the count.

```
for (int i = start; i < count + start; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

You can even increment more than one variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++, start++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(start);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop as below

```
int userInInt, userIntStart;
Console.Write("How many integers do you want to print? ");
userInInt = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("What is the first integer you want printed? ");
userIntStart = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

     for(int counts = userIntStart; counts < userIntStart + userInInt; counts++)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(counts);
     }
```

The problem to your initial code is that your for loop is wrong, first you should assign to `counts` the initial value, then you should provide correct exit condition in the second arg and third arg is increment step which is 1, have a look at `for` loop syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for).

Answer (score 0):

In your code first you need to use the correct variable name in increment step(++). Secondly please note, you need to use a separate variable to keep track of number of integers. In my case, I am using variable 'i' for that. Hopefully it will help.

```
     int userInInt, userIntStart;
        Console.Write("How many integers do you want to print? ");
        userInInt = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("What is the first integer you want printed? ");
        userIntStart = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int i = 0;

        for (int counts = userIntStart; i<userInInt; counts++,i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(counts);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```